# What is the probability of getting 3 heads in 4 coin tosses, given you get at least 2 heads?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I came across this question while doing conditional probability questions and while I can get the answer by counting outcomes, I'm getting a different answers using Bayes' theorem. $\ P(2T)\ $ is the probability of getting at least 2 tails. $\ P(3T)\ $ is the probability of exactly 3 tails. We flip a fair coin 4 times and are looking for the probability of getting 3 heads given we get at least 2 heads.
$$P(3T|2T) = \frac{P(2T|3T)P(3T)}{P(2T)}$$
$$P(2T|3T) = 1$$
$$P(2T) = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$P(3T) = \frac{3}{8}$$
$$P(3T|2T) = \frac{2}{3} $$

The answer is supposed to be $P(3T|2T) = \frac{4}{11}$ which is easy enough to see when the outcomes are counted but there's clearly a problem with the above method I'm using.

Comment: Your events are not clear.  Does "$2T$" refer to the event "you get *at least* two Tails"?  If so, How could you have $P(2T)<P(3T)$?

Comment: Your event $2T$ should be $\ge2T$; $P(\ge2T)=\frac{11}{16}$, and $P(3T)=\frac14$.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity, I've updated the question to reflect the fact that P(2T) refers to the probability of at least 2 tails, whereas P(3T) refers to the probability of exactly 3 tails. (I know, not exactly great notation...)

Comment: You might start by saying that you have flipped a fair coin $4$ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear from your question whether your asking for the probability of *exactly three* heads, but that's what I'll assume.

Given that there are *at least* two heads, the number of cases are as follows:

- Exactly $2$ heads:  ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ cases
- Exactly $3$ heads:  ${4 \choose 3} = 4$ cases
- Exactly $4$ heads:  ${4 \choose 4} = 1$ case

Of these $11$ equally likely cases, four have exactly $3$ heads.  Hence the probability is $P(3|2) = \frac{4}{11}$.

Comment: Thanks, I confused myself with my own poor notation and got the probability for exactly 2  heads rather than at least 2 heads...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, [the tree diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_diagram_(probability_theory)) is the easiest way to tackle those problems (I wish I had learned it sooner)